# Как пройтись in_array в многомерном массиве?

Tags: php

Нужно проверить есть ли `$arItem['ID']` в двухмерном массиве `$arBasketItems`.

Comment: Хорошо, а что конкретно вызывает у вас затруднения?

Comment: плохое знания php, не нашел нужного, а сам написать функцию для поиска не смогу

Comment: У вас есть хотя бы какие-то предположения, как пройти по двухмерному массиву, как сравнивать элементы ? Вы пробовали посмотреть "похожие" вопросы и ответы которые вам предложил сайт на панели справа?

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что здесь скорее всего нужно использовать цикл foreach

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать foreach, можете использовать for, while, while/do, это будет самое простое и читаемое решение.

Можете также использовать array_walk или array_map, чтобы решить эту задачу в функциональном стиле.

Но я бы вам порекомендовал использовать рекурсивные функции, чтобы не заморачиваться со вложенностью массива.